# Upstart: ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, importerror, upstart

I have a simple python script

```
import boto3
print('I know you are installed')
```

I'm sure the boto3 module is installed

```
pip3 install boto3
```

If run via terminal

```
python3 test.py
```

I get the expected output

```
I know you are installed
```

If I run the same script via Upstart

```
description "test"
author "me"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn

chdir /var/www/html/

script
    exec nohup /usr/bin/python3 -u /var/www/html/test.py > 
/var/www/html/test.log
end script
```

I get

```
tail: /var/www/html/test.log: file truncated
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/test.py", line 1, in <module>
import boto3
ImportError: No module named 'boto3'
```

Why can't the boto3 module be found when running the script from Upstart?

Comment: Are you using virtual environment on terminal? Just checking.

Comment: not sure what you mean. I'm logging in ssh, cd'ing to /var/www/html and issuing the command python3 test.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended having to add the following to my script

```
sys.path.append("/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages")
```

Seems as though when running python via Upstart, even though it was using 3.5 it wasn't looking in that site-packages directory